# SAS : How to ignore errors?

Tags: sas, batch-processing

My SAS code contains multiple`data` steps and `proc sql` --> unrelated to one another . Some of them might throw an error . When this happens the rest of the code will terminate .

I need my code to keep on executing . Even if an error is thrown , just put it to the log `ERROR : ...`  but still keep on executing . How can I do that ?

I tried some of the options [from here](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrcon/62955/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000993436.htm)

`options noerrorabend;`

But I could not find anything useful

Comment: Added [tag:batch-processing] since this will only occur in that mode.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd be careful doing this in production, but it appears that you can get back into normal processing mode by putting this line after every one of your data steps and procs that are prone to error.  It basically undoes the usual mode that SAS switches into when it encounters an error.

```
options obs=max nosyntaxcheck;
```

Comment: Agree with the 'do not do this in production'.  Do. Not. Do. This. In. Production. For. Any. Reason.  Full stop.  Production jobs should not have any errors, and any jobs that are distinct from one another should be separately scheduled.

Comment: actually, sometimes errors ARE unavoidable and need to be handled - usually by log scanning.  Agreed that this should be a 'last resort' method though!

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a design problem.

Put each of your unrelated steps into different `.sas` files.  If they're not related they shouldn't be in the same file anyway.

Call each .sas file individually from a UNIX script, or windows batch file, or SAS scheduler, or whatever it is you happen to be using.

If one of them has issues, it will not impact the next one in any way.

**EDIT :** Do **NOT** try to call them one after another by using a SAS `%include` statement, as this will use the same SAS session, and the problems from one will impact the next.